# Change the old password

Tags: php, jquery, html

hi guys im just a new programmer can you help me with this,
i cant change the password and keep saying error on the echo "Password Change Successful";

please help me.
thank you.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["login"]))

    {

        if(!empty($_POST['oldpass']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
            {
                $oldp=$_POST['oldpass'];



                // connection
                $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysqli_error());
                mysqli_select_db($con,'databaseprac') or die("cannot select DB");

                // select database
                $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE password='".$oldp."'");
                $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);




                if($numrows!=0)
                {
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
                {
                    $dbpassword=$row['password'];


                    //mysqli_close()
                    }

                    if($oldp == $dbpassword)
                    {

                     $sql="UPDATE tblusers SET password='$oldp' WHERE id='1';
                        $result=mysqli_query($sql);
                        if($result)
                         {
                        echo "<h4>Password Change Successful</h4>";
                        }
                    }
                    } 
                    else {
                        echo "<h4>Invalid Old Password</h4>";
                    }

             } 

                  else {
                      echo "<h4>All fields are required.</h4>";
                  }
          }
?>
```

Comment: \*sigh\* Obligatory, your code is SQL injectable, comment.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `"` at the end of this sentence:
`$sql="UPDATE tblusers SET password='$oldp' WHERE id='1';`

Also you need to add `$con` to this line:
`$result=mysqli_query($sql);`
like this:
`$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);`

Comment: Not to mention escaping or parameter binding.

Answer (score 1):

You missed out `"` at:

```
$sql="UPDATE tblusers SET password='$oldp' WHERE id='1';
```

Tip: You should prevent `MySQL Injection`:

```
$oldp = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $row['oldpass']);

$dbpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $row['password']);
```

Comment: @VinceGraphic You're welcome, maybe accept the best answer if it helped you by clicking the tick mark

Answer (score 0):

Replace your below code:

```
 $sql="UPDATE tblusers SET password='$oldp' WHERE id='1';
 $result=mysqli_query($sql);
```

with

```
 $oldp = mysqli_real_escape_string ($con, $row['oldpass']);
 $sql="UPDATE tblusers SET password='$oldp' WHERE id='1'";
 $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

1. You missed `"`
2. You are not passing connection string.

Comment: Not to mention escaping or parameter binding.

Answer (score 0):

> here is your code totally working.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["login"]))
   {
      if(!empty($_POST['oldpass']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
        {
            $oldp=$_POST['oldpass'];
            $newPassword=$_POST['password'];
           echo $oldp."  ".$newPassword;
           // connection
            $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','suryabhan') or die(mysqli_error());
            mysqli_select_db($con,'databaseprac') or die("cannot select DB");

            // select database
            $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE password='".$oldp."';");
            $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);


          if($numrows!=0)
            {

                $dbpassword;
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
            {
                $dbpassword=$row['password'];
                echo"password from db:".$dbpassword;

                //mysqli_close()
                }

                if($oldp == $dbpassword)
                {
                  echo"old and new matches";
                    $sql="UPDATE tblusers SET password='$newPassword'WHERE id='1';";
                    $result1=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                    if($result1)
                     {
                    echo"<h4>Password Change Successful</h4>";
                    }
                    else{echo "failed";}
                }
                } 
                else {
                    echo"<h4>Invalid Old Password</h4>";
                }

         } 

              else {
                  echo "<h4>All fields are required.</h4>";
              }
      }
?>
```

> use some text editors like sublime and any one.